# Dual of a Consequence (nomenclature)

Tags: logic, philosophy

More of a naming question:

If $A \Rightarrow B$, then $B$ is a *consequence* of $A$.

If $A \Leftarrow B$, then $B$ is a *¿what?* of $A$?

Background: I am thinking about [Hoare logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic), which has a so-called [*consequence rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic#Consequence_rule). I have something dual in mind, where the implications go the other direction and I would like to name it *¿what? rule*.

Comment: I think the closest term to what you want is probably "antecedent."

Comment: I also saw (on wikipedia) that "antecedent" is dual to a "consequent". But I guess I am looking for a dual to the notion/concept of "consequence". "Antecedence"?

Comment: Yeah, or "precedence" I suppose. You could also go with "nsequence" on general category theoretic grounds. :P

Comment: As I am quite weak categorically, that would be hypocritical, but I see where you're coming from :-D

Comment: ["In an argument, the *conclusions* follow from its premises; its conclusions are *consequences* (follow from) of its premises"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-consequence/)